# Memory leak when delegate is called from "dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),{" block

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I want to do async URL request (with UrlRequestor class)  from MyViewController class:

```
UrlRequestor * urlRequestor = [UrlRequestor alloc] init]];
```

I set MyViewController class as delegate of UrlRequestor class:

```
urlRequestor.delegate = self;
```

And I call to getUrlData function:

```
[urlRequestor getUrlData];
```

It the getUrlData  function in UrlRequestor.m file I dispatch queue for multi-threading. it looks so:

```
- (void) getUrlData {
    .......
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
           NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
           ......
           dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
               ........
               [self.delegate receivedGetData: parsedResponseData withActionCode: [NSNumber numberWithInt: DASHBOARD_REQUEST_DONE]];
           }
    }
}
```

I run the Profile Leaks tool and I received memory leak 100% in the last row:

```
[self.delegate receivedGetData: parsedResponseData withActionCode: [NSNumber numberWithInt: DASHBOARD_REQUEST_DONE]];
```

I am new in iOS and I don't have any idea why I have here memory leak. Thanks for help.

Comment: I tried now "Analyze". It's a good tool , thanks. But there are no any warning around the files from this question.

Comment: We should probably move this to chat: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37800/memory-leak-when-delegate-is-called-from-dispatch-asyncdispatch-get-main-queue